# lack of basic params

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a form that runs payments to PayPal using the PayPal sandbox environment. The script has been running successfully for almost a year until today when I received

```
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/shoppingcart/error?flowlogging_id=1ab83c49aa903&code=LACK_OF_BASIC_PARAMS
```

I can not find anything online for this and my script has not changed at all.

Comment: Same here. Did you fix it?

Comment: Just getting the same error without changing the code... did you found a solution?